# Trying to get total costs in each row jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to get the total costs from each row. Here is a screenshot how that actually looks:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZgLt.png

As you can see 1 row already has its total calculated through the multiplication 5 *2. But this only occurs in the first row, but I gladly want it to be calculated in each row. I think its because of the same name variable in each row, thats why javascript cant calculate the total for each row. I think I need a for loop to fix this. But I really don't know how. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
@foreach ($project->projecttask as $pt)
              <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $pt->task['task_name'] }}    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="projectId" value="{{$project->id}}"/>
                    {{Form::hidden('hour', $project->hour)}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::text('hour', $pt->hour, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'hour')) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::text('hour_salary', $pt->hour_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'hour_salary')) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                {{ Form::text('total_salary', $pt->total_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'total_salary', 'disabled')) }}
                {{--    {{ Form::text('total_salary', $project->total_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'total_salary', 'disabled')) }}--}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <input id="check1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check" >
                            <span class="caret-hover caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
                            <li><a href= "{{ route('user.projecttasks.destroy',array( $pt->id )) }}" data-method="delete" >Delete</a></li>                
                        </ul>   
                     </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
@endforeach

<script>

$(function(){

    updateTotal();

});

    var updateTotal = function(){

        var hour_salary = parseFloat($("#hour_salary").val()); // get number as float
        // alternately parseInt(string, 10), in case you work with integers

        var hour = parseFloat($("#hour").val());

        if (!isNaN(hour_salary)) { // the input is a number
            $("#total_salary").val(hour_salary * hour); // update second field
        } else { // the input wasn't a number
            $("#total_salary").val("not a number?"); // show an error mesage
        }

    };

        // we used jQuery 'keyup' to trigger the computation as the user type
    $("#hour_salary").keyup(function() { // when key is released in "#inputfield1"
    // "change()" is also possible instead of "keyup()", slightly different behavior
        updateTotal();

    });

        // we used jQuery 'keyup' to trigger the computation as the user type
    $("#hour").keyup(function() { // when key is released in "#inputfield1"
    // "change()" is also possible instead of "keyup()", slightly different behavior

        var hour_salary = parseFloat($("#hour_salary").val()); // get number as float
        // alternately parseInt(string, 10), in case you work with integers

        var hour = parseFloat($("#hour").val());

        if (!isNaN(hour_salary)) { // the input is a number
            $("#total_salary").val(hour_salary * hour); // update second field
        } else { // the input wasn't a number
            $("#total_salary").val("not a number?"); // show an error mesage
        }
    });

  </script>
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: looks like you have multiple elements with the same ID... id of an element must be unique.... use classes to group similar elements

Comment: Could you post the resulting HTML, instead of the template/script?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery or javascript. Are those tags relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but I have already fixed this with the following code (for those who are interested):

```
@foreach ($project->projecttask as $pt)
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ Form::select('id_task', array('0' => 'no task selected', 'tasks'=>Task::lists('task_name','id') ), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        {{$pt->hour}}
                        <input type="hidden" name="projectId" value="{{$project->id}}"/>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ Form::text('hour', $pt['hour'], array('class' => 'form-control hour', 'data-row'=>$pt->id , 'id'=>'hour' . $pt->id )) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ Form::text('hour_salary', $pt->hour_salary, array('class' => 'form-control hour_salary', 'data-row'=>$pt->id , 'id'=>'hour_salary' . $pt->id )) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    {{ Form::text('total_salary', $pt->total_salary, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'total_salary' . $pt->id, 'disabled')) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <input id="check1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check" >
                                <span class="caret-hover caret"></span>
                            </button>
                          {{  $pt->id }}
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
                                <li><a href= "{{ route('user.projecttasks.destroy',array( 'id' => $pt->id, 'project' => $project->id )) }}" data-method="delete" >Delete</a></li>

                            </ul>   
                         </div>
                    </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
<script>

$(function(){
    //$('#test').css('color','red');
    updateTotal();

});

    var updateTotal = function(rowId){
        var rowId = rowId,

            $hour_salary =  $("#hour_salary" + rowId),
            $total_salary =  $("#total_salary" + rowId);

        var hour = parseFloat($("#hour" + rowId).val()),
            hour_salary = parseFloat($hour_salary.val()); 

        if ( hour_salary.length > 0 ) 
            $total_salary.val("0"); 
        else
            $total_salary.val( hour_salary * hour );
    };

    $(".hour_salary").keyup(function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        //wrm row ipv data-row?
        var rowId = $this.data('row');

        $this.val( $this.val().replace(/\D/g,'') );

        updateTotal( rowId );
    });

    $(".hour").keyup(function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        var rowId = $this.data('row');

        $this.val( $this.val().replace(/\D/g,'') );

        updateTotal( rowId );

    });

  </script>
```

To be actually honest I had received help from my internship supervisor to make this code.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, first off you should be using classes here rather than IDs. You should only have unique IDs on the same page.

Secondly, you probably want to limit your calculations to the same row, by grabbing the current row of the event and finding the elements to change within that.

Thirdly, you don't need to separate your keyup functions, that just makes more work of things. In fact, as that second keyup function is a copy of updateTotal, its is completely unnecessary:

```
// Added a variable that this function accepts, "row", so it knows its location in the document
var updateTotal = function(row){

    // Define all elements as descendants of the "row" passed in
    var salary = row.find(".hour_salary"),
        hour = row.find(".hour"),
        total = row.find(".total_salary");

    var salaryVal = parseFloat(salary.val());

    var hourVal = parseFloat(hour.val());

    // Added another check for hourVal being a number as well
    if (!isNaN(salaryVal) || !isNaN(hourVal)) {
        total.val(salaryVal * hourVal);
    } else {
        total.val("not a number?");
    }

};

//Run same keyup function for both text boxes
$(".hour_salary, .hour").keyup(function() {

    // Find the row
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // Pass in the row
    updateTotal(row);
});
```

NOTE: I have changed all your ID selectors to classes, so this will not work until that is reflected in your HTML.

Hope this helps.